# Caine Linux v10 installation gives error: Operation not permitted during write on /dev/sda

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Caine Linux.

I downloaded ISO from https://www.caine-live.net/ and "burned" it with Rufus to a memory stick. Then I bootet from this memory stick to Caine Live.

In Caine Linux I made disks writeable by clicking the harddisk icon on the status bar -> then click Install 18.04 on desktop.

On installation type I selected "Erase disk and install 18.04" Here I got the error "Operation not permitted during write on /dev/sda".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unblock the drive you are installing to making the device writable, using the unblock GUI. All drives are initially set to read only.

When you make the change, the GUI will refresh, showing you the writable devices. Just leave the dialog box open and install.